# Distribute application via ad hoc iPhone/iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, xcode4, publish

I need to send an application to someone before submitting it to the app store. I have already sent the file and when my friend tries to sync the app iTunes says that a signature is missing. I don't understand what I am doing wrong so let me show you all the things that I've done.

(I will demonstrate this with an iPhone app instead of an iPad app since I don't have an iPad with me and I believe the process should be about the same).

so in order to be clear I want to start from the begining and I deleted all the certificates that I have created. so my keychain looks like:

[image][image]

so as you can see I don't have any certificates nor keys so far. Moreover in my provisioning portal I have deleted all the certificates plus as many things as I could:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I did not know how to delete these profiles:

[image]

THE REASON WHY I TRY TO DELETE AS MANY THINGS AS I COULD WAS BECAUSE I WANTED TO MAKE MY SELF CLEAR HOPING YOU GUYS WILL UNDERSTAND MY QUESTION. I HAVE BEEN TRYING TO SEND THIS APP FOR A LONG TIME AND I WOULD GREATLY APPRECIATE IF SOMEONE COULD TELL ME WHAT AM I DOING WRONG.

anyways lets say that the app I want to send to my friend is the following:

[image]

[image]

and when I run it in the simulator I get:

[image]

ok so now everything looks great I am ready to send my friend this great app that I just build so I will go ahead and start creating the certificates so that he can install it in his computer:

(I don't think I have to create this but I will)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

and then I have imported that certificate:

[image]

ok now I click on refresh and add that new certificate to keychain access:

[image]

so far I am done with my development certificate.

I will go ahead and perform the same steps but with the Distribution Certificate:

[image]

..

...

...

the steps should be the same as for the last step. and I end up with:

[image]

[image]

.

.

ok now let me add "my friends" UIID number:

[image]

[image]

.

.

now I will create my app id:

[image]

[image]

.

.

know I am ready to create a distribution provisioning profile:

[image]

[image]

[image]

.

.

.

ok know from looking at this list:

[image]

I have completed steps 1,2 and 3 I believe. So I will then go ahead an send him FooApp.app and distribution provisioning profile:

[image]

and finally I have those files on the windows computer:

[image]

and when I drag them into iTunes and I sync the device I get the following error:

[image]

WHAT AM I DOING WRONG. I HAVE FOLLOWED THE INSTRUCTIONS FROM THE INTERNET AND I CAN MAKE IT WORK.

---

EDIT

I believe that my problem is in this part:

[image]

why does xcode says that no profiles currently match?????

[image]

the instructions that I read from:

[image]

never mentions nothing about the build part on settings!

Comment: I know pictures are worth 1000 words, but that's just ridiculous... :)

Comment: haha I know but if you read through it you can go pretty fast. I just throw as many pics as I could. Wanted to make sure people could understand me. I am starting to dislike apple stuff. I am new to objective c plus I believe I followed all the steps from the description from the site and I am not ale to make it work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check that the app is correctly signed?
Is it using the correct Code Signing Identity under your Project Settings?

Comment: The page description does not mention that so I guess I have not check that. What exactly do I have to check?

Comment: Check "Code Signing Identity" under your Project Settings. If it's empty it means you didn't import your provisioning in XCode. If you see your profile, but you can't select it, you gave your application bundle the wrong name.

Answer (score 0):

Did you send the other person the adhoc mobileprovision file along with the app?  You need to do that in order for them to install it.  ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles

Comment: but hold on I think I have to add that file to xcode then build it then send the new app along with the file. I am about to do that right now

Comment: Yes.  You have to make sure the AdHoc provisioning profile is being used by XCode to build the AdHoc distribution.

Comment: Thanks a lot Adrian. Yeah take a look at my edit.. that is what you mean right? I am not able to change it...